# How can i remove duplicate code od dictionary in c#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am working with `Dictionary` to display messages. For that I used `Dictionary` to add messages and parse it to display function. Below is my code:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();

dict.Add("","");

service.displaymessage(dict);
```

This code is repeated in my class to add different messages in every function.
How to minimize these line?

Comment: How many `dict.Add("","")` you have in each repeated code?

Comment: And... do you create a `new` dictionary for each call to `Add` as your question indicates?

Comment: You can create a method that takes in dictionary, adds an element and displays it.

Comment: Why do you need `Dictionary` to pass just a single message? Do you have need to pass multiple messages from a single function?

Comment: yes there are multiple messages